# no code but got an error "Invalid character in identifier"

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

I used PyPDF2 moduel to write a small program and it worked. However, one day later (I may change something on the code, but not sure about that), I got an error like this:

**File "1111.py", line 2, in 
    import PyPDF2
  File "/Users/yangchunxin/Desktop/py/PyPDF2.py", line 91
    def get_pagenum(filename，key_word):
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier**

I checked everything, but did not figure it out. *So I deleted everything just keep the first line.
import PyPDF2*

I still got the same error message. There were no line 91, only one line :import PyPDF2

I tried to import other modules and they worked. *Then I uninstall PyPDF2 module and import PyPDF2. The same error message was obtained.* So strange to me!

Could anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I used atom and it looks like atom has the error memory!

Comment: Your comma looks like it comes from a different charset (based off your name, a Chinese full width comma?). Try this one to test if it works: `,`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I did change key_word to keyword. The same error message was obtained. I deleted all code just keep "import PyPDF2" and got the same error. But there is nothing in line 91. By the way, I used mac. Thank you.